# Nodejs DynamoDB CreateTable hash only with no range returns ValidationException

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, create-table

I am trying to create a table on [dynamodb](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) trough their [aws-sdk on nodejs](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js).
Below is the parameter I am passing on dynamodb.createTable:

```
{
    TableName: 'new_table',
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    },
    KeySchema: [
        {AttributeName: 'primary_key', KeyType: 'HASH'}
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        {AttributeName: 'primary_key', AttributeType: 'S'},
        {AttributeName: 'some_attribute', AttributeType: 'S'}
    ]
}
```

This returns

```
ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Number of attributes in KeySchema does not exactly match number of attributes defined in AttributeDefinitions
```

I have fixed this by adding 'some_attribute' on 'KeySchema' but what I want is a 'hash' only table with no 'range'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved: When creating a table, you only need to specify the KeySchema attributes and not all attributes that you will be putting on the table. So in my case I just need to specify the 'primary_key'

```
{
    TableName: 'new_table',
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    },
    KeySchema: [
        {AttributeName: 'primary_key', KeyType: 'HASH'}
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        {AttributeName: 'primary_key', AttributeType: 'S'},
    ]
}
```